# Resolve-DnsName powershell command not working with -CacheOnly switch

Tags: powershell

I'm testing the `Resolve-DnsName` powershell command on Windows 10 and noticed that it doesn't return hits, even though the entry is in the DNS cache (that I get with `ipconfig /displaydns`).

I launched an administrator powershell.

I'm trying for example:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> Resolve-DnsName www.ebay.co.uk -CacheOnly
Resolve-DnsName : www.ebay.co.uk : DNS record does not exist
At line:1 char:1
+ Resolve-DnsName www.ebay.co.uk -CacheOnly
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (www.ebay.co.uk:String) [Resolve-DnsName], Win32Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : RECORD_DOES_NOT_EXIST,Microsoft.DnsClient.Commands.ResolveDnsName
```

The entry appears in the cache as:

```
www.ebay.co.uk
----------------------------------------
Record Name . . . . . : www.ebay.co.uk
Record Type . . . . . : 5
Time To Live  . . . . : 6
Data Length . . . . . : 8
Section . . . . . . . : Answer
CNAME Record  . . . . : ipv4.slot11847.ebay.com.edgekey.net
```

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: does it show in `Get-DNSClientCache | Format-Table -AutoSize` ? I just tested by doing `Resolve-DnsName www.ebay.co.uk` and then the first command. It appears. Then I can successfully add the `-CacheOnly` flag and re run the Resolve-DNS command.

Comment: Here's another variation to try specifying the record type with the `-CacheOnly` works for www.google.com on my side but adding the Type A record I do get results returned. Works --> `Resolve-DnsName -Name www.google.com -Type A -CacheOnly`. Does not work --> Resolve-DnsName -Name www.google.com -CacheOnly`. Out of time to dig but quick observation.

Comment: None of the two work.  (excuse the late answer)  Thanks!